# Read i18n from different JSON files [React-i18nnext]

Tags: reactjs, react-i18next

I am new to react-i18nnext library. I try to separate my translations into files so that each page has a separate JSON-file and not one single.

I am confused about how to do the following step from [this guide](https://react.i18next.com/guides/multiple-translation-files):

[image]

---

## How am I trying to implement i18n from other files:

I am using the following code to call default `translate.json` file:

```
<h1>{t('title')}</h1>
```

But I want to call a different file, so I have to use according to the guide:

```
<h1>{t('test:title')}</h1>
```

if I use file `translation.json` - everything works, but if I am using another name of the file - it fails with error:

```
i18next::translator: missingKey en test title title
```

files in my app:
[image]

---

### Other code

I followed the ["Step by Step"](https://react.i18next.com/latest/using-with-hooks) guide on the official page of the library.

Here's my `i18n.js` file:

```js
import i18n from 'i18next';
import { initReactI18next } from 'react-i18next';

import Backend from 'i18next-http-backend';
import LanguageDetector from 'i18next-browser-languagedetector';
// not like to use this?
// have a look at the Quick start guide
// for passing in lng and translations on init


const languages = ['en', 'de', 'et'];

i18n
    /*
     load translation using http -> see /public/locales (i.e. https://github.com/i18next/react-i18next/tree/master/example/react/public/locales)
     learn more: https://github.com/i18next/i18next-http-backend
    */
    .use(Backend)
    /*
     detect user language
     learn more: https://github.com/i18next/i18next-browser-languageDetector
    */
    .use(LanguageDetector)
    /*
     pass the i18n instance to react-i18next.
    */
    .use(initReactI18next)
    /*
     init i18next
     for all options read: https://www.i18next.com/overview/configuration-options
    */
    .init({
        lng:"ee",
        fallbackLng: 'et', // use et if detected lng is not available
        saveMissing: true, // send not translated keys to endpoint
        debug: true,
        whitelist: languages,

        // backend: {
        //     // for all available options read the backend's repository readme file
        //     loadPath: '/locales/{{lng}}/{{ns}}.json'
        // },

        react: {
            useSuspense: false
        }
    })


export default i18n;
```

For a better overview, I added my code  to codesandbox:

[image: Edit vibrant-black-s40r5]

Comment: How did you setup your i18next?

Comment: @felixmosh  Hi! I updeted my question with the  `i18n.js`-file.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In order to use multiple namespaces in the same page, you need to specify it when calling `useTranslation`.

```js
export default function App() {
  const [t] = useTranslation(["translation", "customFile"]);
  // ---------------------------------------------^

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <button onClick={() => changeLanguageOnClick("en")}>English</button>
      <button onClick={() => changeLanguageOnClick("de")}>German</button>
      <h1>{t("title")}</h1>
      <h2>{t("customFile:title")}</h2>
    </div>
  );
}
```

This is how it look like:
https://codesandbox.io/s/intelligent-shockley-q588u?file=/src/App.js:243-304

Comment: Thanks a lot! I found actually a guide to this there, but if they included that there (what u wrote) - that could be helpful